# using column in sub query within SELECT

Tags: mysql-5.7, subquery

I have the following SQL that uses column inside a `SELECT` within a `SELECT` in the `FROM` clause. It looks like it is not supported. ATM I see no alternative beside splitting this into two queries.

Users comments on songs (besides its own):

```
select users.id,
      (select count(distinct c.songId)
       from comments c
       inner join songs s on c.songId = s.id
        and s.userId <> tdu.id       <------ this is where the issue is
       where c.userid=tdu.id
       and c.del IS NULL
       limit 1 ) as co
from (select id from users1 where id between 100 and 200 limit 10) users
join users2 AS tdu on users.id = tdu.id
```

DDL

```
create table users1 (id int);
create table users2 (id int);
create table comments(
  id int,
  comment,
  songid int,
  userid int,
  del int);
create table songs(
  id int,
  songid int,
  userid int);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'tdu.id' in 'on clause'
```

My questions are

How can I use `tdu.id` inside SQL within `SELECT`

BTW i would love to remove the `LIMIT 1` there since obvious it returns one row, but MySQL fails without it.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: the join problem is easy but you  have two questions in one, that is not good , but even so a full [mre] with all tables is not only helpful, but also needed

Comment: The data is not so important to me, as the goal of this question is to be able to run it. I wanted to keep this question simple.

Answer (score 2):

For syntax (and naming) reasons, you would need to change to:

```
select
   users.id,
   (select count(distinct c.songId)
       from c
       inner join s on c.songId = s.id
--       where c.userid=tdu.id
       where c.id=tdu.id
       and s.userId <> tdu.id     --  <------ this is where the main issue was
       and c.del IS NULL
       limit 1 ) as co
from (select id from users1 where id between 100 and 200 limit 10) users
-- join users2 AS tdu on users.userId = tdu.id
join users2 AS tdu on users.Id = tdu.id
;
```

There is no **tdu** joined to in the sub-select. That's why you need to push that condition to the `where` clause.
And there is no **userid** in either one of **c** and **users**.

Verify the syntax to be valid: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f3fc2/1).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

NB: I've no 5.7 installation available to double check.

Comment: I made some adjustments to my question to make it clearer. Moving `s.userId <> tdu.id` won't result in different result set?

Comment: Right now, I see renamed tables and an added column. This won't affect the outcome. Strictly speaking, there was no result set in the first place. (As a side note: In the old days, there was no explicit `JOIN` - it had to be done in the `WHERE` clause.) With the syntactically correct statement, there might be a non-empty result set. Whether it matches your intentions is hard to tell with no sample data and no expected outcome. Not sure how exactly to read the added "Users comments..." - but's not what I had guessed from the statement.